# Why is Cobra flags not working in this code

Tags: go-cobra

How to get flags to work in Cobra using Local [flags](https://github.com/spf13/cobra/blob/master/user_guide.md#local-flags)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/spf13/cobra"
)

func main() {
    myCmd := &cobra.Command{
        Use: "myaction",
        Run: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
            if len(args) == 1 {
                flags := cmd.Flags()
                var strTmp string
                flags.StringVarP(&strTmp, "test", "t", "", "Source directory to read from")
                fmt.Println(strTmp)
            }
        },
    }

    myCmd.Execute()
}
```

#### Error

```
go run main.go myaction --test="hello"
Error: unknown flag: --test
Usage:
  myaction [flags]

Flags:
  -h, --help   help for myaction
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Run` part of the command gets executed only after the `Execute` is called on the command (you can also have a [prerun-hook](https://github.com/spf13/cobra/blob/master/user_guide.md#prerun-and-postrun-hooks).)

So in your case when execute is called the runtime doesn't know about the flag. We should add the flags before the `Execute` is called on the command to make the runtime aware of it.

## Code

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/spf13/cobra"
)

func main() {
    var strTmp string
    myCmd := &cobra.Command{
        Use: "myaction",
        Run: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
            if len(args) == 1 {
                fmt.Println(strTmp)
            }
        },
    }
    myCmd.Flags().StringVarP((&strTmp), "test", "t", "", "Source directory to read from")
    myCmd.Execute()
}
```

## Output

```
⇒  go run main.go myaction --test "hello"
hello
```

But there is an alternate solution to this, when you want to add the flags based on a condition. You can set `DisableFlagParsing` to `true` and parse it later.

## Code

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/spf13/cobra"
)

func main() {
    myCmd := &cobra.Command{
        Use: "myaction",
        RunE: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) error {
            if len(args) > 1 {
                flags := cmd.Flags()
                var strTmp string

                // Add the flag
                flags.StringVarP(&strTmp, "test", "t", "", "Source directory to read from")
                
                // Enable the flag parsing
                cmd.DisableFlagParsing = false

                // Parse the flags
                if err := cmd.ParseFlags(args); err != nil {
                    return err
                }

                fmt.Println(strTmp)
            }

            return nil
        },
    }

    // Disable flag parsing
    myCmd.DisableFlagParsing = true
    myCmd.Execute()
}
```

## Output

```
⇒  go run main.go myaction --test "hello"
hello
```